# primes whose difference is a multiple of $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Hello everyone this is my first question here so if there are any suggested edits  feel free to participate!
Is it true that for every $n$ there two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ with $n\mid p-q$?
I have verified this empirically but  am not sure if there is a proof for this

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A204894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Dirichlet's box principle, if we take the first $n+1$ primes $2=p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{n+1}$ at least two of them must have the same remainder when divided by $n$. So there is a solution of:
$$ p_i\equiv p_j\pmod{n} $$
with $i\neq j$ and $\max(p_i,p_j)\leq C n \log n$. Obviously, large prime numbers may fall only in $\varphi(n)$ residue classes $\!\!\pmod{p}$, so the previous inequality can be improved a bit. At last, the [Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombieri%E2%80%93Vinogradov_theorem) proves that primes are almost uniformly distributed over the previous residue classes. However, to provide explicit bounds for the [Chebyshev's bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias) is an extremely difficult problem.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. This is true. There are only finitely many ($n$ to be precise) residue classes modulo $n$. There are infinitely many primes. Therefore (by the pigeonhole principle) at least one of the residues classes must contain more than a single prime (actually infinitely many, but that's besides the point). If $p$ and $q$ are two primes in the same residue class then their difference is divisible by $n$.

Comment: My answer is very similar to yours, just a more quantitative version. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but I don't expect it's trivial.

To prove it, choose any prime q not dividing n.  Then look at the congruence $$x \equiv q \;\; mod \,n$$

By Dirichlet's theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions there are infinitely many prime solutions and any of these will work.

Comment: Note:  my method is overkill, as the answer posted by Jyrki Lahtonen clearly points out.  If there is any value in my answer at all (not clear) at least it demonstrates that you can use any q (or p, by similar argument) not dividing n.

Comment: It is valuable (for that very reason). I was one of your early upvoters. Confession time: my first reaction was to use Dirichlet, too :-)

Comment: Ah, but you were patient enough to search for a better way to go whereas I....